# How to create dataframe using results (output) of pairwise.t.test

Tags: r, dataframe

My df:

```
df <- data.frame(
    measurement = runif(120, min=1, max=25),    
    group = rep(c("A","B","C","D"), each=3, times=10)
)
```

performing t.test and putting results on new df

```
ttest_results <- data.frame(pairwise.t.test(df$measurement, df$group))
```

I get this error:

```
Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = stringsAsFactors) : 
  cannot coerce class ""pairwise.htest"" to a data.frame
```

I found this solution that works, but i honestly want to solve this through R

```
write.table(test[["p.value"]], file="output.csv", sep=",")
```

Comment: You can directly do `as.data.frame(pairwise.t.test(df$measurement, df$group)$p.value)`.

Comment: Is it possible to format data for ggplot?

Comment: You should probably as it as a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following comment of @user3710546, here is how you can get **p-values** output for pairwise comparisons:

```
# Create dummy dataframe
df <- data.frame(
  measurement = runif(120, min=1, max=25),    
  group = rep(c("A","B","C","D"), each=3, times=10)
)

# Run  your test and save it to its own object
ttest_results <- pairwise.t.test(df$measurement, df$group)

# Get p-values in a dataframe
ttest_results$p.value
```

While adding the $ symbol in RStudio, you can notice that p-values area actually stored in a table.

[image]

Which results :

```
  A         B  C
B 1        NA NA
C 1 0.3999325 NA
D 1 1.0000000  1
```

Now you can nicely display your p-values and check the pair-wise comparisons:

```
# Convert the data to a table
m<-as.table(p.vals)


# Plot p-values
# ----------------------
library("gplots")

windows(3,3)
balloonplot(t(m), 
            main ="p.values", 
            xlab ="", 
            ylab="",
            label = FALSE, 
            show.margins = FALSE)
```

[image]